# How can I tell which DNS servers DNSMasq is using?

Tags: dns, dnsmasq

How can I tell which DNS servers DNSMasq is using to resolve a name to an IP address?
I can't figure it out.  All of the existing questions here seem to just go as far as telling users that they are using DNSMasq.

Comment: Add this to your config: `log-facility=/var/log/mydnsmasq.log` and then run a nslookup on your domain and tail the log file, you will see which server was used.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can find the DNS servers with the NetworkManagerCLI (`nmcli`) tool:

```
nmcli dev show | grep DNS
IP4.DNS[1]:                             172.22.216.251
IP6.DNS[1]:                             2a01:4f0:400c:1::1
```

## Ubuntu 14.04 and older

The command is slightly different in older (<15.04) versions of Ubuntu:

```
> nmcli dev list | grep DNS
IP4.DNS[1]:                             172.22.216.251
IP6.DNS[1]:                             2a01:4f0:400c:1::1
```

Comment: Don't you mean `nmcli dev show`?

Comment: @einpoklum: No. On my 14.04 box, `nmcli dev show` gives: `Error: 'dev' command 'show' is not valid.`

Comment: On my Lubuntu 15.10 I get the opposite.

Comment: Note that this answer assumes that dnsmasq is managed by NetworkManager. You can verify this in `pstree`: the dnsmasq process should be a child of NetworkManager. This is the case at least on Ubuntu 16.04 Desktop, but I'm not certain about older or newer versions, or the Server edition.

Answer (score 28):

For a more generic answer when you are using dnsmasq *without* network manager and with *several* upstream DNS :

```
sh# kill -USR1 <PID OF DNSMASQ>
sh# tail /var/log/syslog
```

Upon receiving SIGUSR1, dnsmasq will log various statistics, **including the number of DNS request send to each upstream server**. Based on that, you can easily determine the most frequently used DNS server on your system.

Comment: Also, when any changes are made to the connection (e.g. connecting to VPN), dnsmasq logs these to /var/log/syslog:
`dnsmasq[xxx]: setting upstream servers from DBus
dnsmasq[xxx]: using nameserver 10.xx.xx.xx#53(via tun0)
dnsmasq[xxx]: using nameserver 192.xx.xx.x#53(via wlp2s0)`

Comment: This is a better answer because it tells you which servers were actually used as opposed to just which servers are configured to be used.

Comment: Thanks, your answer gave me a hint to look into the logs, I used `sudo journalctl -b -u dnsmasq | grep nameserver`.

Answer (score 3):

Generally, for the system using `systemd`, the DNS servers `dnsmasq` is using can be found via

> `journalctl -u dnsmasq`

Comment: This does not work when `dnsmasq` is launched by NetwokrManager (and configuration is passed via dbus)

Answer (score 1):

In package:

```
network-manager 0.9.8.8-0ubuntu7.2 amd64
```

The command is:

```
root@D-MIS-001:~# nmcli dev show | grep DNS
IP4.DNS[1]:                             172.16.10.173
IP4.DNS[2]:                             172.16.10.133
```

This is what seems to be the current package version for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.  The correct command for 15.* may have changed.

Comment: You probably mean `show` instead of `list`, since `list` is not a valid command

Answer (score 1):

It's also possible to ask NetworkManager by DBus directly. (This is what *nmcli* does under the hood). For example, on Ubuntu 14.04 or later, run (without the leading `$`):

```
$ env -i gdbus introspect -y -o /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/IP4Config -d org.freedesktop.NetworkManager | perl -ne 'if (m@^  node (\d+) [{]$@) { $_ = readpipe("env -i gdbus introspect -y -o /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/IP4Config/$1 -d org.freedesktop.NetworkManager\n"); while (m@ Nameservers = \[(?!\])((?=\d)[\d, ]*\d)\]@g) { for (split(m@, *@, $1)) { print join(".", unpack("C4", pack("I", $_))), "\n" } } }'
12.34.56.78
90.123.45.6
```

For a more indirect approach, use `ActiveConnection` instead of `IP4Config`.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 15.04 the command is:

```
$ nmcli dev show | grep DNS
IP4.DNS[1]:                             8.8.8.8
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm expanding the answers given by others, showing sligthly longer commands, which print only the DNS servers.

Ubuntu 14.04 has *nmcli* 0.9.8.8 in the *network-manager* package. The list of DNS servers is within the output of `nmcli -f IP4 -t -m tabular dev list`. To get only the list of DNS servers, run (without the leading `$`):

```
$ env -i nmcli -f IP4 -t -m tabular dev list | perl -ne 'chomp; my @l = split(m@:@, $_); if (@l > 3) { $_ = $l[3]; if (m@^\d+(?=[.])[\d. |]+[.]\d+$@) { for (split(m@ *[|] *@, $_)) { print "$_\n" } } }'
12.34.56.78
90.123.45.6
```

Ubuntu 15.04 or later also has *nmcli* in the *network-manager* package, but expects different command-line arguments. The list of DNS servers is within the output of `nmcli -f IP4.DNS -t -m tabular dev show`. To get only the list of DNS servers, run (without the leading `$`):

```
$ env -i nmcli -f IP4.DNS -t -m tabular dev show | perl -ne 'if (m@^\d+(?=[.])[\d. |]+[.]\d+$@) { chomp; for (split(m@ *[|] *@, $_)) { print "$_\n" } }'
12.34.56.78
90.123.45.6
```

Since *nmcli* connects to NetworkManager via DBus, the command above works for any connections managed by NetworkManager, even for those which don't use *dnsmasq*. However, not all connections are managed by NetworkManager. The list of DNS servers should be extracted from the file `/etc/resolv.conf`, and if it contains addresses starting with `127.0.`, NetworkManager should be consulted. Here is how to extract:

```
$ perl -ne 'print "$1\n" if m@^\s*nameserver\s+(\S+)\s*$@' /etc/resolv.conf 
127.0.1.1
```

Please note that `127.0.1.1` (and possibly others) indicates *dnsmasq*, and `127.0.0.53` indicates *systemd-resolved*.

If the current active connection is not managed by NetworkManager (and *systemd-resolved*), then the DNS servers will be enumerated in the file `/etc/resolv.conf`.