# How to find out which DNS server my wlan0 is using Kubuntu 15.04

Tags: networking, kubuntu, dns

**BACKGROUND**

I am trying to find out what DNS server is being used when I connect to the internet with my wlan0 device.  I am running Kubuntu 15.04.

I have searched around and tried a few solutions, none of which work for me.  Here is what I have tried:

1.
Using the nmcli command

```
nmcli dev list | grep DNS
```

as per an answer to the similar question asked [here.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/556852/how-can-i-tell-which-dns-servers-dnsmasq-is-using)

This was marked as the answer for the OP, but for me I just get the following output:

> Error: 'dev' command 'list' is not valid.

2.
Reading resolv.conf:

```
cat /etc/resolv.conf
```

This does not give me the DNS information for my connection.

3. Using nm-tool

nm-tool does not appear to be installed on my system.  So that's not the correct answer for me.

4. Using dnsmasq

There are a few answers which involve the use of dnsmasq.  But in all cases I have not understood the answer enough to use it and I don't know what dnsmasq is.

**QUESTION**

How do I find out what DNS a connection is using, via the command line or GUI, with Kubuntu 15.04?

### **[EDIT]**

It appears that I have had difficulty in articulating this question, because many people have provided answers which - whilst correct - are not quite the answers to the question I had in mind.  Here is my attempt at clarification:

The answers provided so far simply give me the address of my router, because my router is responsible for providing the internet connection.  But the question I really had in mind was; what *internet* DNS server is used when I type, for example, "www.google.com" into an internet browser?

I thought this would be relatively easy to find out, mainly because it's easy to dictate which internet DNS server is used myself.  I can, for example, bring up my connection settings and tell it to use 8.8.8.8 for DNS, which is Google's public DNS server.  My question, then, is; if I don't dictate any specific DNS server, and leave the router to use whatever it is assigned, how do I find out which DNS server(s) it is using?

Comment: `nm-tool` is discarded as of 15.04. It's still useful on earlier versions, however, like 14.04

Comment: Also the reason why `nmcli dev list` doesn't work is because `nmcli` version in 15.04 is different, hence uses different commands. mgor's answer bellow is the correct way to do it in 15.04

Comment: Thanks.  It appears that my question is confusing, because many people have provided answers which - while correct - do not answer the question I intended.  And it may be that my lack of understanding has caused the difficulty in the way I've articulated the question.

The answers posted simply give me the address of my router.  Which makes some sense to me, because my router is the thing that provides the internet connection.  But I wanted to know what happens when I type "www.google.com", for example.  Which internet DNS server resolves this? And how do I find out.

Comment: I thought it would be simple to find out, because I know that I can set the internet DNS server that will be used if I want.  e.g. I can configure my router to use 8.8.8.8, which is Google's internet DNS server.  If I don't make any such setting, and leave the router to use the DNS server it is assigned, how do I find out which one it is using? That's my real question.

Comment: You've asked originally for `wlan0` interface, hence people answered accordingly. What you really ask is DNS router uses and you can find that out only through the router itself. I've updated my answer

Answer (score 5):

With nmcli you can check which dns servers dnsmasq is configured with:

```
nmcli dev show wlan0 | grep -i dns
```

An example would be:

```
$ nmcli dev show wlan0 | grep -i dns
IP4.DNS[1]:                             10.11.12.1
IP4.DNS[2]:                             10.11.13.1
```

Comment: My preferred way. +1

Answer (score 2):

**Update**: As revealed in the comments bellow the question, OP wants to know the DNS server that the router uses. If you use automatic connection, all of the answers given here will tell you address of your router, which means requests go to your router first.The router in turn has its own settings, which forward whatever DNS request you send to router's DNS.

*Finding out what DNS server is used on a router is only possible if you access your router's settings, typically for residential routers through `192.168.0.1`.*

**TL;DR**: Version 1 - check syslog. Version 2 - send packets with `nslookup` or `dig` and see where they go to; more advanced and technical answer, but definitely more fun and in my opinion is a bit more reliable.

The other answers posted above are great and work 99% of the time. In this answer I would like to provide somewhat alternative, more technical solution with `nslookup`. Another simpler solution is to check `/var/log/syslog`.

**The syslog method**

The simple method is to search with `grep` tool for `using nameserver` string in `/var/log/syslog/` :

```
$ sudo grep 'using nameserver' /var/log/syslog                                                                                                     
Aug  6 02:25:34 ******** dnsmasq[1487]: using nameserver 208.67.220.220#53
```

**The tcpdump and nslookup method**

Here's not so simple method but perhaps more reliable. Since observing where dns requests go will tell us what is the real dns server we can do exactly that. There is such tool as `tcpdump`. It is used to analyse the packets send by the internet adapters. Frequently , this tool is used in pen testing. For our modest purpose of determining dns, we only need to do two things - run at the same time `tcpdump` and use another tool `nslookup` (which actually helps to look up domain names using system's dns server) . Specifically we want to look for packets with that go to `.domain` destinations. For instance, I run `sudo tcpdump -c 50 -i wlan0 > tcpdump-result.txt` to capture 50 packets from my wireless adapter, and immediately go to another terminal tab and run `nslookup google.com`. For convenience I also output `tcpdump` result to a file `tcpdump-result.txt`

Now, using a little bit of knowledge of such tools as `grep` and `awk`, I filter out the desired information about `.domain`:

```
$ awk '/.domain/ {gsub("my-host-name","****");print}' tcpdump-result.txt                                                                 
01:49:48.811363 IP ****.local.29258 > 192.168.0.1.domain: 11608+ PTR? 69.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa. (43)
01:49:49.095361 IP ****.local.44184 > google-public-dns.domain: 9560+ A? google.com. (28)
01:49:49.139361 IP google-public-dns.domain > ****.local.44184: 9560 1/0/0 A 216.58.217.46 (44)
```

As you can see , my request goes to 192.168.0.1, which is my home router. Therefore , it means you are using DNS server that your Internet Service Provider has assigned to you.

Now, what if we change dns and do it all over again ?

```
$ awk '/.domain/ {gsub("my-hostname","****");print}' tcpdump-result2.txt                                                                
02:05:35.885670 IP ****.local.51056 > resolver2.opendns.com.domain: 2511+ A? google.com. (28)
02:05:36.189665 IP ****.local.5503 > 192.168.0.1.domain: 63991+ PTR? 220.220.67.208.in-addr.arpa. (45)
02:05:36.237664 IP 192.168.0.1.domain > ****.local.5503: 63991 1/0/0 PTR resolver2.opendns.com. (80)
02:05:36.241664 IP ****.local.27776 > 192.168.0.1.domain: 58334+ PTR? 69.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa. (43)
```

Now my requests go to opendns ! But which IP specifically ?

ping resolver2.opendns.com

```
PING resolver2.opendns.com (208.67.220.220) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from resolver2.opendns.com (208.67.220.220): icmp_seq=1 ttl=57 time=59.9 ms
64 bytes from resolver2.opendns.com (208.67.220.220): icmp_seq=2 ttl=57 time=55.9 ms
^C
--- resolver2.opendns.com ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1003ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 55.999/57.999/59.999/2.000 ms
```

As you can see it goes to `208.67.220.220`

Comment: A novel =) great work

Comment: Thanks very much indeed for taking the time to provide this answer.  It is much more complex to find this out than I thought it would be!

I will give your suggestions a try over the weekend, thanks.

Comment: Brian, see my updated answer. If you're trying to find out what DNS server is used by your router, you have to access the router settings

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways:

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.1.1         **<--Server**
search localdomain
```

or

```
$ dig localhost

; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-3ubuntu0.4-Ubuntu <<>> localhost
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 47070
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;localhost.         IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
localhost.      0   IN  A   127.0.0.1

;; Query time: 1 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.1.1#53(127.0.1.1)         **<--Server**
;; WHEN: Wed Aug 05 11:30:10 EDT 2015
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 54
```

It turns out that the question was "I would like to find out which DNS servers are being used when I use my internet connection to resolve a hostname to an ip. i.e. when I use my internet browser to browse to www.amazon.com, which DNS server translates that into an ip ".

Now, the answer is:

For an existing connection, you cannot. DNS address resolution has happened and is over before you can open the connection.

To see what nameservers are used to resolve a DNS query, you could `dig +trace  @$( grep nameserver /etc/resolv.conf| awk '{print $2}' | head -n1 ) amazon.com`

`dig` is from the `dnsutils` package.

Comment: I don't believe either of those methods will give me the information I'm looking for.  I'm not certain that you've understood my question in the way that I intended.

I would like to find out which DNS servers are being used when I use my internet connection to resolve a hostname to an ip.  i.e. when I use my internet browser to browse to www.amazon.com, which DNS server translates that into an ip so that I connect to the service I wanted?

I realise that it is possible to set which DNS servers should be used. I haven't done this, but I would like to query which ones are being used by default.

Comment: I understand, but will have to awnser fully later. You want to know, if your system asks "`amazon.com`"?, what happens between then and "`72.21.206.6`". It is called "DNS address resolution". Google may be your friend, but I have a bus to catch.

Comment: I understand what DNS is, I am trying to find out which DNS servers are used to complete those requests for a particular connection.  i.e. when I connect to the internet, via my ISP, which DNS servers are they setting for me by default.  I can change it of course (e.g. set it to a 3rd party DNS such as 8.8.8.8.) but I want to know what DNS servers are being used, at this moment, if I don't set anything different myself.

Comment: But, beyond the server in `/etc/resolv.conf` it is dynamic!

Comment: I understand it is dynamic. I'm not trying to predict the DNS server address, I want to find out what it is at any given moment.

Comment: Use `dig` from the `dnsutils` package: `dig +trace @127.0.0.1 amazon.com` and read the OReilly "DNS & Bind" book

Comment: Replace `127.0.0.1` with your nameserver or `$( grep nameserver /etc/resolv.conf| awk '{print $2}' | head -n1 )`

Answer (score 0):

To show all DNS for each network device, except `lo`:

```
for i in /sys/class/net/*; do \
    awk -F/ '! /lo/ {system("nmcli dev show "$(NF)" | grep \"DNS\|DEVICE\"")}' <<< "$i"; \
done
```

*Example output*

```
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         eth0
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.20.1
```